# Is it possible to simulate spacing between table cells such that vertical and horizontal spacing are different?

Tags: html, css, css-tables

In CSS, you can specify the spacing between table cells using the border-spacing property of a table.

However, this results in uniform spacing between columns and rows, and I am finding more situations where the designs I am using call for gaps between rows, but not columns, or visa versa.

If I have a solid background, I can simulate spacing using borders the same colour as the background colour.

I could also make a div (for example) the first child of every table cell, and using either padding or margins to get the desired results, but that is a lot of extra markup just to accommodate the style.

Given that that the data I am displaying is tabular data, is there a sensible way to achieve this style using tables?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You *can* specify different spacings for horizontal and vertical edges for `border-spacing` or related properties. Just specify more than one measurement. e.g.,

```
border-spacing: 1px 2px;
```

Comment: I feel I've made a fool of myself. It appears that you can only specify two lengths though, not four.

Comment: Thanks! Yes, border-spacing is indeed special. Most other margin/border-like properties do allow specifying four values, not just two, but obviously this one is different.

Comment: I wouldn't worry about feeling foolish: even if it's a question that you feel you should have known, someone else with less experience may not have had an idea, and now they will.

Answer (score 6):

In the ***general case*** where you may specify calues thayt may be applied globally or individually on a property (for example, "padding"), follow a simple pattern.

- If you specify a single value (e.g.
  padding:2px; ) the value is applied
  to the top, bottom, left and right
  of the object.
- If you specify two values (e.g.
  padding:2px 7px; ) the first value
  is applied to the top and bottom and
  the second to the left and right.
- If you specify three values, the
  first value is applied to the top,
  the second value to the left *and*
  right, and the final value to the
  bottom.
- If you specify four values (e.g.
  padding:1px,2px,3px,4px; ) the
  values are applied to top,  right,
  bottom, left in that order (remember the order using the word  TRouBLe).